# C++: How do I prevent modification of a derived object through a pointer to its base subobject?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants, implicit-conversion, type-safety

The following simplified (yet compileable) example illustrates a possible slice-assignment scenario.

```
#include <string>

struct Base
{
    // Mutating method. Not a chance of making it virtual.
    template <typename Anything>
    Base& operator=(const Anything& x)
    {
        m_int = x.AsInteger();
        return *this;
    }

    int AsInteger() const
    {
        return m_int;
    }

    int  m_int;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    template <typename Anything>
    Derived& operator=(const Anything& x)
    {
        m_text = x.AsString();
        Base::operator=(x);
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string& AsString() const
    {
        return m_text;
    }

    // Invariant: Derived::m_text matches Base::m_x.
    std::string   m_text;
};

void ExamineBase(const Base* b)
{
    b->AsInteger();
}

void ExamineBase(const Base& b)
{
    b.AsInteger();
}

void InitBase(Base* b)
{
    *b = Base();
}

void InitBase(Base& b)
{
    b = Base();
}


int main()
{
    Base           b;
    InitBase(b);          // <----- (1)
    InitBase(&b);         // <----- (2)

    Derived        d;
    Derived&       ref = d;
    Derived*       ptr = &d;

    ExamineBase(ref);     // <----- (3)
    ExamineBase(ptr);     // <----- (4)

    InitBase(ref);        // <----- (5)
    InitBase(ptr);        // <----- (6)

    return 0;
}
```

Lines (1), (2), (3) and (4) are good.

Lines (5) and (6) exhibit a problem: they change only the base subobject within a complete object, obviously breaking the coherence between Base::m_int and Derived::m_text.

I'm interested in preventing such slice-modification from happening, yet preserving the validity of lines (1), (2), (3) and (4).

So the questions are:

a) Are there any tricks that may prevent calling non-const member functions of a base class through a pointer to a derived class?

b) Are there any tricks that may block standard implicit conversion from `Derived*` to `Base*`, but still allow conversion from `Derived*` to `const Base*`?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but it sounds like you have a really iffy design with such a requirement. The whole point of inheritance is that you want a "is-a" relationship. My gut feeling is that `Base` should be a member of `Derived` instead.

Comment: Sorry for not addressing this aspect in the question... Yes, you're right. Inheritance may not be the right thing for this relation. I just want to allow the use of `Derived` in every place where non-mutating access to `Base` is enough. To draw you a picture, lets imaging that `Base` is a non-owning accessor like `std::span` and `Derived` is some class from a family of owning containers.

Comment: A virtual copy assignment operator will probably work.

Comment: @NathanOliver Would that prevent the pointer up-casting?

Comment: @Frank It wouldn't prevent the cast but it should make `b = Base();` call `Derived`'s `operator =` since that is what it actually is.

Comment: @NathanOliver, unfortunately making all mutating methods (or operators) virtual is not an option. Virtual methods can't be templates, and having it template is essential. For one, a class may accept a variety of initializer types. Another reason is that mutating operator may come with some sfinae stuff, so that std::is_assignable would report correct results.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, it would prevent that specific use. I guess I was overbroadening OP's question to mutations in general.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I am answering the question as asked, but if you are wondering how to achieve this, then odds are more than likely that something is wrong with your design.

Short answer: this cannot be done with public inheritance, full stop. The whole point of public inheritance is that a referenece or pointer to an object of `Derived` can be used as a reference or pointer to an object of `Base`, regardless of context.

So, the way to do this would be to go through private inheritance, or a member variable, and only expose the `Base` member through an accessor returning a `const` reference or pointer:

```
#include <string>
struct Base
{
    // Mutating method. Not a chance of making it virtual.
    template <typename Anything>
    Base& operator=(const Anything& x)
    {
        m_int = x.AsInteger();
        return *this;
    }

    int AsInteger() const
    {
        return m_int;
    }

    int  m_int;
};

struct Derived : private Base
{
    template <typename Anything>
    Derived& operator=(const Anything& x)
    {
        m_text = x.AsString();
        Base::operator=(x);
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string& AsString() const
    {
        return m_text;
    }

    const Base& base() const {return *this;}

    // Invariant: Derived::m_text matches Base::m_x.
    std::string   m_text;
};

void ExamineBase(const Base* b)
{
    b->AsInteger();
}

void ExamineBase(const Base& b)
{
    b.AsInteger();
}

void InitBase(Base* b)
{
    *b = Base();
}

void InitBase(Base& b)
{
    b = Base();
}


int main()
{
    Base           b;
    InitBase(b);          // <----- (1)
    InitBase(&b);         // <----- (2)

    Derived        d;
    Derived&       ref = d;
    Derived*       ptr = &d;

    ExamineBase(ref.base());     // <----- (3)
    ExamineBase(&ptr->base());     // <----- (4)

    InitBase(ref.base());        // <----- BOOM!
    InitBase(&ptr->base());        // <----- BOOM!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Frank, but the necessity to make an explicit call to a conversion function (that is, `base()`) is exactly what I was hoping to avoid... I was hoping to use `Derived` everywhere a `const Base` would fit. That's why I started with 'is-a' relationship: `Derived` is-a `Base` in every non-mutating context.